# NetworkOnMainThread Exception - parsing data the right way

Tags: android, android-asynctask

iam developing an android app for parsing a json data set into my app. But everytime iam getting a NetworkOnMainThred exception:

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

On this line:

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

After that ive tried fixing it by puttin the progress in an AsyncTask Inner Class. But that has no effect iam getting the same error. Is the AsyncTask really essential?
Here the whole context:

```
question.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Connector db = new Connector();
            db.executeAction();//calls AsyncTask

        }
    });




public class Connector extends Activity {
    View rootView;
    ArrayList<String> resultset = new ArrayList<String>();
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }
public void executeAction() {
    new LongOperation().execute();
}

private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        testDB2();
        return null;
    }
    public void testDB2() {

        String result = "";
        //the year data to send
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("year", "1980"));

        //http post
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://quizmaster.esy.es/db_con.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream is = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();

            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.question)
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        ArrayList<String> resultset = new ArrayList<String>();
        //parse json data
        try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                resultset.add(String.format(json_data.getString("Frage")));
                Log.i("log_tag", "id: " + json_data.getInt("ID") +
                                ", Frage: " + json_data.getString("Frage")
                );
            }
        }


        catch(JSONException e)
        {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    }
}
```

}

Invocation:

```
public class Connector extends Activity { 
    View rootView; 
    ArrayList<String> resultset = new ArrayList<String>(); 

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */ 
    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    } 

    public void executeAction() { 
        new LongOperation().doInBackground(); 
    }
```

Comment: The `httpclient.execute()` step isn't on the main thread in the code you posted. How are you executing the AsyncTask?

Comment: `code`public class Connector extends Activity {
    View rootView;
    ArrayList<String> resultset = new ArrayList<String>();
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }

    public void executeAction() {
        new LongOperation().doInBackground();
    }

Comment: First, never manually call the `doInBackground()` method, it's called by the framework some time after you call `execute()` on the `AsyncTask`. Second, see @323go's answer.

Comment: ive updated the code now how the Connector Activity is called, may it helps understanding

Answer (score 2):

Your `onPostExecute()` contains a call to `testDB2()`. `onPostExecute()` is executed on the main thread. Thus the exception.

Further, you *never* call `doInBackground()` directly. Instead, you would invoke the AsyncTask as:

```
new LongOperation().execute();
```

Comment: ive now try it with the execute. but the testDB2() dont get called now.

Comment: Did you fix your calls to `LongOperation`?

Comment: yes i do it like your suggestion but now the onpreexecute trigger is only called which runs in the main thread too

Comment: Of course... `onPreExecute()` and `onPostExecute()` or called on the UI thread, `doInBackground()` is called on a background thread. This is [well documented](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) behavior.

Comment: but i cant identify while debugging that the method is called. and there is no result in the resultset variable afterwards.

Comment: First get rid of the `String.format()` -- that's pointless there. Does the logcat show your results? What happens when you check the content of `resultSet` in `onPostExecute()`? Most likely, you're just checking too soon.